# How to store an event that was clicked and automatically display in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, session

How can I do that when I clicked a dropdown then I redirect to another page then I go back to the previous and the dropdown should be open?. My colleague told me that I don't need session or even cookies for this.

Comment: You can use `localStorage`.

Comment: Is this the easiest way?

Comment: Yes. There are other methods, but `localStorage` is simply an Object that persists for a specific domain.

Comment: Thanks man. Already fixed my problem.